# 「参照カウント法の原理」を試したいのですが、xdebug_debug_zval()の結果がマニュアルと異なるのはなぜ？

Tags: php

**[参照カウント法の原理](http://php.net/manual/ja/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)を試したいのですが、xdebug_debug_zval()の結果がマニュアルと異なります。**

---

**環境**
・PHP7.1.2
・xdebug2.5.1

---

**コード**

```
$a = "new string";
xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' );
$b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' );
xdebug_debug_zval( 'b' );

$x = "new string";
$y = &$x;
xdebug_debug_zval( 'x' );
xdebug_debug_zval( 'y' );
```

---

**結果**

```
a:
(refcount=0, is_ref=0)string 'new string' (length=10)
a:
(refcount=0, is_ref=0)string 'new string' (length=10)
b:
(refcount=0, is_ref=0)string 'new string' (length=10)
x:
(refcount=2, is_ref=1)string 'new string' (length=10)
y:
(refcount=2, is_ref=1)string 'new string' (length=10)
```

---

**Q.**
・バージョンの問題ですか？
・それとも、xdebugの設定が何か必要でしょうか？

Comment: [Internal value representation in PHP 7 - Part 1](https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html): この記事にはPHP5とPHP7でのZend valueの実装の違いが詳しく解説されているので読んでみて下さい。簡単には、PHP5では `A concept that is closely related to reference counting is "copy on write": A zval can only be shared between multiple users as long as it isn't modified.` で、PHP7では `The new zval implementation in PHP 7. The fundamental change that was implemented, is that zvals are no longer individually heap-allocated and no longer store a refcount themselves.` だそうです。したがって、「 参照カウント法の原理」はPHP5での実行例かと思います。

Comment: リンク提示ありがとうございました。リンク先に詳細が書いているようなので、そちらで試してみたいと思います。大変参考になりました